# How to exec self with command-line arguments added to stdin?

Tags: perl, scripting, exec, command-line-arguments, stdin

**EDIT:** just to clarify, I want to know how one would implement the piping of content to an `exec`'d process, *putting aside* the question of whether Perl offers better ways to achieve the same end-result that don't involve this technique.

---

It's easier to describe what I want to do with a *toy* `zsh` script example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# handle command-line arguments if any
# nb: ${(%):-%x} is zsh-speak for "yours truly"

# (( $# % 2 )) && (print -rl -- "$@"; [[ -t 0 ]] || cat) | exec ${(%):-%x}
(( $# > 0 )) && ([[ -t 0 ]] || cat; print -rl -- "$@") | exec ${(%):-%x}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# standard operation below this line

nl
```

The script above is pretty much a pass-through wrapper for the `nl` ("number lines") utility, except that, if command-line arguments are present, it will append them to to its stdin.  For example:

```
$ seq 3 | /tmp/nlwrapper.sh
     1      1
     2      2
     3      3
$ seq 3 | /tmp/nlwrapper.sh foo bar baz
     1      1
     2      2
     3      3
     4      foo
     5      bar
     6      baz
```

Note that

1. the command-line arguments could have just as easily been *prepended* to stdin (in fact, if one uncomments the script's 7th line, the resulting script will prepend or append the command-line arguments to stdin depending on whether their number is odd or even, respectively); *I am interested in both functionalities*.
2. the script consists of two *entirely independent* sections: a preamble that handles the command-line arguments (if any), and the body (in this toy example consisting of a single line) that takes care of the script's main functionality (numbering lines); *this is an essential design feature*.

To elaborate on these two points a bit further: the "body" section knows *nothing* about the business with the command-line arguments.  The code that implements this handling of command-line arguments could be prepended pretty much "as-is" to any `zsh` script that processes stdin.  Moreover, changes to how the command-line arguments are handled (prepend vs append, etc) leave everything below the comment `# standard operation below this line` untouched.  The two sections are *truly* independent of each other.

---

What would be the equivalent of the preamble above in a Perl script?

---

I know that the Perl-equivalent of the script above would have the general form

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use English;

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# handle command-line arguments if any

if ( @ARGV > 0 ) {

   # (mumble, mumble)   ...   -t STDIN   ...   exec $PROGRAM_NAME;

}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# standard operation below this line

printf "%6d\t$_", $., $_ while <>;
```

My problem is implementing this bit:

```
([[ -t 0 ]] || cat; print -rl -- "$@") |
```

I do know that

1. the `[[ -t 0 ]]` test in Perl is `-t STDIN`;
2. the `cat` part could be implemented with `print while <>`; and
3. the `print -rl -- "$@"` bit could be implemented with `CORE::say for @ARGV`

What I don't know is how to put these elements together to get the desired functionality.

Comment: Use `print while <>` instead of `print for <>` to avoid memory wastage and prevent holding things up until stdin reaches eof.

Comment: @Borodin: sorry, that was a typo; fixed now; thanks!

Comment: You should know by now that you pretty much never get an explanation for votes, but I know it's frustrating.

Comment: @Borodin: I know; every once in a blue moon requesting for an explanation does work, though...

Comment: I think that tactic may work rather better if you weren't so scathing about the character of the voter! You could ask a general question: "I see that I have a downvote. Can anyone see what may be wrong with my post?"

Comment: @Borodin: thank you for your patience; point taken.

Comment: @kjo It may be just me, but I don't really understand what you're after. (I don't know details of `zsh` and can't parse the example.)  To prepend/append command-line arguments (?) to ... what otherwise would be the script's output ("main functionality")?  Or is it more involved? I don't see a reason to spawn extra processes.  (Sure you can, in many ways, back and forth. It's just better not to if not needed.)

Comment: @kjo As for the segregation of processing that you want, that requirement is cleanly handled by writing a module.  Then you just `use` it, and call its subs as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be easier just using `cat` with some common shell features. (`bash` used here.)

```
cat <( seq 3 ) <( printf 'foo\nbar\nbaz\n' ) | prog
```

---

Solution:

```
use POSIX qw( );

sub munge_stdin {
   pipe(my $r, my $w) or die("pipe: $!");
   $w->autoflush();

   local $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
   defined( my $pid = fork() ) or die("fork: $!");
   if (!$pid) {
      eval {
         close($r) or die("close pipe: $!");

         while (<STDIN>) {
            print($w $_) or die("print: $!");
         }

         for (@ARGV) {
            print($w "$_\n") or die("print: $!");
         }

         POSIX::_exit(0);
      };

      warn($@);
      POSIX::_exit(1);
   }

   close($w) or die("close pipe: $!");
   open(STDIN, '<&', $r) or die("dup: $!");
   @ARGV = ();
}

munge_stdin();
print while <>;   # or: exec("cat") or die("exec: $!");
```

- This solution supports `exec()` in the Perl script.
- This solution won't deadlock no matter how large the inputs are.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the Perl script needs to be as cryptic as the shell script, I would do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autouse Carp => qw( croak );

use IO::Interactive qw( is_interactive );

run( \*STDIN, is_interactive() ? [] : (\@ARGV, [qw(ya ba da ba doo)]) );

sub run {
    my $appender = mk_appender(@_);
    printf "%6d\t%s", @$_ while $_ = $appender->();
}

sub mk_appender {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $line_number = 0;
    my $i = 0;

    my @readers = (
        sub { scalar <$fh> },
        (
            map { my $argv = $_; sub {
                ($i < @$argv) ? $argv->[$i++] . "\n" : ();
            }} @_
        ),
    );

    return sub {
        @readers or return;
        while ( @readers ) {
            my $line = $readers[0]->();
            return [++$line_number, $line] if defined $line;
            shift @readers;
            $i = 0;
        }
        return;
    };
}
```

Output:

```
$ seq 3 | perl t.pl foo bar baz         
     1  1                               
     2  2                               
     3  3                               
     4  foo                             
     5  bar                             
     6  baz                             
     7  ya                              
     8  ba                              
     9  da                              
    10  ba                              
    11  doo
```

Some advantages of using the facilities offered by Perl instead of trying to replicate the shell script include the fact that you can avoid spawning additional processes, reading through the entire standard input twice etc.

I also write about reading from multiple files at the same time in [How to sum data from multiple files in Perl?](https://www.nu42.com/2016/06/sum-multiple-files-using-perl.html)

If you are intent on reading the same input twice, see [pipe](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pipe.html) and [Bidirectional communication with yourself](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Bidirectional-Communication-with-Yourself).

Comment: Questions of legibility/clarity/good design/etc. aside, is it really not possible for a Perl script to do a self-exec maneuver like the one I showed (i.e. one where content is piped to the exec'd process)?